# написал код для дс бота но есть оишбки

Tags: python, discord.py

Написал код для бота модератора в дс, все запускается и работает, но когда он должен давать варн за слова, он жалуется на строку "54" (Ниже дам код)
Что пишет:

```
[2023-10-20 14:00:02] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-10-20 14:00:03] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 71481dcaf3ac219ae3935197c7563b83).
- ������� ���� -

��� ����: Moderator bot
ID ����: 1164590511110242335
����� ����: MTE2NDU5MDUxMTExMDI0MjMzNQ.GWNE1K.HzbSjx3IaS8MsqduvduSmv71feJmeZLJuMB6UE

[2023-10-20 14:00:15] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\magic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\magic\Desktop\discrod bot\main.py", line 54, in on_message
    for i in range(0, len()):
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

код:

```
import discord 
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import time
import json

from discord.ext import commands 
from discord.utils import get 

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

TOKEN = "MTE2NDU5MDUxMTExMDI0MjMzNQ.GWNE1K.HzbSjx3IaS8MsqduvduSmv71feJmeZLJuMB6UE"

BADWORDS = ["лох"]
LINKS = ["https", "http", "://", "com", "ru", "net", "org", "shop"]

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("- АККАУНТ БОТА -")
    print ()
    print(f"Имя бота: {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"ID бота: {bot.user.id}")
    print(f"Токен бота: {TOKEN}")
    print()

    if not os.path.exists("user.json"):
        with open("users.json", "w") as file:
            file.write("{}")
            file.close()


    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            with open("users.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                file.close()

                with open("users.json", 'w') as file:
                    data[str(member.id)] = {
                        "WARNS": 0,
                        "CAPS": 0
                    }

                    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
                    file.close()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    WARN = BADWORDS + LINKS

    for i in range(0, len()):
        if WARN[i] in message.content.lower():
            with open("users.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                file.close()

            with open("user.json", "w") as file:
                data[str(message.author.id)]["WARNS"] += 1
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

                file.close()

            emb = discord.Embed(   
                titl="Нарушение",
                description=f"*Раннее, у нарушителя было уже {data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] - 1} нарушение*",
                timestamp=message.created_at
            )
            

            emb.add_field(name="Канал:", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Нарушитель:", value=message.author.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="тип нарушения:", value="Ругательства/ссылки", inline=True)

            await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=1164868575891308544).send(embed=emb)
            
            if data[str(message.author.id)]["WARNS"] >= 7:
                await message.author.ban(reason="Вы превысили допустимое количество нарушений!")
            
    if message.content.isupper():
        with open("users.json", "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            file.close()

        data[str(message.author)]["CAPS"] += 1
        
        if data[str(message.author.id)]["CAPS"] >= 3:

            with open("users.json", "w") as file:
                data[str(message.author.id)]["CAPS"] = 0
                data[str(message.author.id)]["WARNS"] += 1
            
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
                file.close()
            
            emb = discord.Embed(   
                titl="Нарушение",
                description=f"*Раннее, у нарушителя было уже {data[str(message.author.id)]['WARNS'] - 1} нарушение*",
                timestamp=message.created_at
            )
            

            emb.add_field(name="Канал:", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="Нарушитель:", value=message.author.mention, inline=True)
            emb.add_field(name="тип нарушения:", value="КАПС", inline=True)

            await get(message.guild.text_channels, id=1164868575891308544).send(embed=emb)
            
            if data[str(message.author.id)]["WARNS"] >= 7:
                await message.author.ban(reason="Вы превысили допустимое количество нарушений!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

---

Исправил for i in range(0, len(WARN)): , бот начал реагировать но также ничего не делает

Comment: `len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` — требуется перевод этого сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: желательно да и помочь как решить

Comment: функции `len()` требуется ровно один аргумент, а вы указали ноль аргументов. решение очевидно: укажите аргументом то, что вам требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Забыли, видимо, аргумент у метода `len()` написать, нужно было видимо так:

```py
for i in range(0, len(WARN)):
                      ^^^^
```

Comment: ну вот и зачем подсказывать так много **автору кода** (как он утверждает)? автор кода ведь должен прекрасно знать, по какому массиву ему в данном месте требуется итерация.